# is cheese sauce a good compromise to eat veggies

Tags: weight-loss, diet

So I've gone in 1 year from abs to flab!  Mostly I have logistical issues with work and studying which leads me to eating unhealthy food, sleeping badly and not exercising.

I've started cooking and plan to cook my food and work into a 30 day cleansing plan where I will work up to eating only boiled vegetables, fruits and poached eggs.

Today I made a cheese sauce with a gracious amount of butter and refined flour, and ate it with spinach and mushrooms and brown rice. Was delicious!

**Question**: (1) Is cheese sauce (milk+butter+flour) a good enough compromise to eat veggies along with it. (2) Is it a feasible plan to work up to eating just small amounts of brown rice and mostly boiled veggies and poached eggs? I'm assuming this will get my weight down considerably enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good plan, well, at all! Simply cutting out all carbs from your diet will have a huge impact.

1. No. Why? Because your are combining carbs and fat and this is a sure bet to spike insulin levels and convert all those carbs to fat. Forget this combo.
2. No. Why? There are a million plans online you can find and most of them (at least now) subscribe to some sort of LCHF (Low Carb High Fat) idea which have been proven in literature to have amazing effects on blood sugar and other health factors. Google Musclehack TSPA and you will, in my subjective opinion, have a very solid plan.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I looked at quite a few plans.So I'm going with just simple meals with a little bit of carbs and mostly boiled food. No cheese sauce.

Answer (score 0):

More calories = you gain weight.  It doesn't matter if it is butter, milk, and flour or some hamburgers.  Actually if you are working out I would go the fast food route since you would get more protein.  If you don't like a "healthful" food that is low in calories then don't worry about eating it.  Slathering it with calories isn't helping the cause.  I would experiment with foods until you found a combo of things you liked that didn't have a ton of calories - hint: low fat meats.

Answer (score 0):

If it is within your macronutrient limit, a sauce like that is neither good nor bad. But a high calorie sauce that includes cheese, butter and flour will make it harder to get under your daily calorie limit.

But, it should be stated that the advice to completely cut out sauces on vegetables isn't the best advice. Fresh vegetables are quite high in vitamins and nutrients that are necessary for good health and muscle growth, however **many vitamins naturally found in vegetables are fat-soluble** - these include vitamins A, D, E and K.

**If you are eating a caloric restriction, ensuring the highest absorption of vitamins from what you eat is important**, so ensure you eat adequate fat to promote absorption of these vitamins.

Additionally, fats help provide feedback to your brain through '[mouthfeel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouthfeel)'. This helps your brain register you have eaten. As a comparison, when you eat a carrot your mouth feels 'clean' very soon after swallowing, while the same carrot with a modest amount of butter will leave a (good) lingering taste in your mouth.

As to what to put on your vegetables, consider **small** amounts of healthy fats and oils such as butter or olive oil, depending on taste. A teaspoon (or less) of these will coat the vegetables making the more palatable and *healthier*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yep, I'm just going with a light fry in olive oil.